# POI enable different header/footer for the first page in word docx file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm generating a docx file using Apache POI 3.13 and I stuck with headers/footers for first page.
I create `XMPFParagraph[]` without any problem. Next I create headers and footers like this (I've tried in different oreder):

```
policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, defaultHeader);
policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, defaultFooter);
policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST, firstHeader);
policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST, firstFooter);
```

Once I generate my docx file I could see my default header/footer on every page including first one. But if I select to use different header/footer for the first page - my first header and footer apperes correctly.
How could I make this happens automaticaly via code? And is there any appropriate documentation with examples about POI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a first page header in a section, you must enter a title page tag in section properties tag (w:sectPr). The title page tag can be empty, but it is necessary. In your case, you can add only 2 code lines:

```
CTSectPr sect = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
sect.addNewTitlePg();
```

`Best regards!